# Show values in descending order by date

Tags: c#, sorting, lambda

I have c# list of data returning 2 dates.

```
5/31/2016 4:34:41 AM
5/31/2016 4:38:08 AM
```

I am using lambda expression to sort them to show latest date on top. But still its showing wrong. What may be the issue.

```
var rowEntities = 
    MyOperations.GetEntitiesByDate().ToList().OrderByDescending(i=>i.JobStartTime);

public DateTime JobStartTime { get; set; }
```

Comment: Can you show what `GetEntitiesByDate` returns ?

Comment: @UweKeim It is already stated that it is of type `DateTime`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var rowEntities = MyOperations.GetEntitiesByDate().OrderByDescending(i=>i.JobStartTime).ToList();
```

Comment: Why should moving the `ToList` call make any difference (beside performance)?

Answer (score 1):

```
var rowEntities = MyOperations.GetEntitiesByDate().ToList().OrderByDescending(i=>i.JobStartTime);
```

or

```
var rowEntities = (from dates in MyOperations.GetEntitiesByDate() orderby dates.jobstarttime select dates).Tolist();
```

or

```
var rowEntities = (from dates in MyOperations.GetEntitiesByDate() orderby dates.jobstarttime ascending or descending select dates).Tolist();
```

Comment: How is this related to with OP's question?

Comment: there is two methods to write linq query, i just wrote the second one, in case the first one is not working